# Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

For non-commutative rings, we have [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Generalization_to_arbitrary_rings) generalization of the Chinese remainder theorem (CRT).
I wonder if there is another statement involving only left or right ideals;
do you know any?

Comment: It is easy to see that if $\{I_i:i<k\}$ are left ideals of a ring $R$, and $I=\bigcap_{i<k}I_k$, then $x+I\mapsto(x+I_0,\dots,x+I_{k-1})$ is an injective $R$-module homomorphism $R/I\to\bigoplus_{i<k}R/I_i$, which is surjective (i.e., an isomorphism) if and only if $I_i+\bigcap_{j\ne i}I_j=R$ for each $i<k$. I do not know if the latter condition can be simplified; in the case of two-sided ideals, it is equivalent to $\{I_i:i<k\}$ being pairwise coprime (i.e., $I_i+I_j=R$ for $i\ne j$), but I do not think this suffices for one-sided ideals.